# Vectorizing/Parallelizing DataFrame indexing

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I want to make the following Python data-processing code more efficient by replacing for loops. Is there any way to vectorize code like this?

1. I have a DataFrame object `df` that looks somewhat like:

   ```
   names number
   bob 5
   sara 10
   bob 8
   foo 12
   moo 16
   ```
2. I want to subset the DataFrame to find out all the rows associated with each name, and then perform an operation on `number`. This is what I am doing now:

   ```
   for myName in set(df['names']):    
       nameSubset = df.loc[df['names']==myName]    
       operation(nameSubset['number'], **args) 

   '''Basically,perform an operation on the `number` column of nameSubset.'''
   ```

Is there any way to make this code run faster? Theoretically, this could be made faster if, instead of running through each myName at a time, the computer could process several myNames at any given moment. I'm not sure how to vectorize/parallelize my code to make this happen though.

Comment: So you want to `group_by(names)`, then do an operation on `number` - is that an aggregation/summary operation (e.g. sum, max, count) or an operation on each individual number, e.g. compute some value)?

Comment: This is all covered by the basic pandas doc, e.g. [Group By: split-apply-combine](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html). Please skim the doc. This is not really a data-science question.

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you want?

```
In [261]: df
Out[261]:
  names  number
0   bob       5
1  sara      10
2   bob       8
3   foo      12
4   moo      16

In [262]: def my_op(ser):
     ...:     return ser.sum()
     ...:

In [263]: df.groupby('names').agg({'number':my_op})
Out[263]:
       number
names
bob        13
foo        12
moo        16
sara       10
```